# In Azure is this possible to run windows service?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service

Scenario is like currently we have Azure virtual machine and we hosted one web app and some windows service on that now we are planning to move web app to Azure websites instead of virtual machines. Now issue is that what about the windows services? Can we host windows services in Azure without virtual machines?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Typically you'd use a [web job](https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/) or [function](https://azure.microsoft.com/services/functions/) for this purpose.

Comment: Can we achieve same functionality that in the windows service with the web jobs?

Comment: If you look at them for background compute, then yes. They're just command line executables or scripts that run scheduled. You have full control over the code. Main difference is the privileges with which they are run. Services can run as SYSTEM, Web Jobs run as app pool user.

Comment: I need database connection and transaction as well in the windows service will this work with the web jobs?